# Variation of the derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations

Suppose we have a function $x(t)$ and a transformation $t \rightarrow t'=t+ \delta t$, and want to find the change in derivative $\delta \frac{d x}{d t}$ due to that transformation. I treat it as kind of differentiation and  get $\delta \frac{d x}{d t} = -  \frac{d x}{d t} \frac{d \delta t}{d t}  $. It is right, isn't it?

Now we want to do the same with a function $u(x^{\mu})$, transformation $x^{\mu} \rightarrow x^{\mu'} = x^{\mu} + \delta x^{\mu}$ and derivative $u_{,\mu}$. It seems that I miss something really fundamental, because the written above approach doesn't work here. Could you help me and say what is it?

I will appreciate any piece of advice.

EDIT: to ones interested in the problem: I was trying to apply this wonderful Feynman's argument to get Noether currents in classical field theory https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19847/97253 .

EDIT 2: the original problem is to derive Noether current (without their usual derivation through looking at global transformation and making them local, but using Feynman's argument in the above link). $S[u, x^{\mu}] = \int_\Omega \mathcal{L}(x^{\mu}, u, \partial u) d^4 x$ is action functional. $x^{\mu} \rightarrow x^{\mu'} = x^{\mu} + \delta x^{\mu}$ - is a transformation under which action is in invariant. I look at the transformation of the form $\delta x^{\mu} = \epsilon(\theta(x^0-x^0_i) - \theta(x^0-x^0_f))*...$, where $\theta(x)$ is step-function. Now I need to variate action. Variation of 4-volume is obvious: $\delta d^4 x = d^4 x \frac{\partial \delta x^\mu}{\partial x^\mu}$ (just variation of Jacobian). Nonobvious for me is variation w.r.t. $\partial u$, which do change when we perform our transformation. It contains calculation of the  $\frac{\partial \mathcal(L)}{\partial u_{,\mu}}\delta u_{,\mu}$, which leads to my question.

Comment: The variation of a functional $F[x(t)]$ is defined by 
$$\frac{\delta{F}[x(t)]}{\delta{x(t')}}=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow{0}}\frac{F[x(t)+\epsilon\delta(t-t')]-F[x(t)]}{\epsilon}$$

Comment: Hi, @KirylPesotski ! Could you clarify what functional you are talking about?

Comment: In your example you have $\frac{dx(t)}{dt}$.

Comment: @KirylPesotski  it is a function but not a functional, isn't it? Or shall i represent it as an integral using delta-function?

Comment: The expression used by @KirylPesotski isn't mathematically well-defined since $F$ takes a function, but $\delta$ is no function. A better definition is
$$\left\langle \frac{\delta F[x]}{\delta x(t)}, \phi(t) \right\rangle = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{F[x + \epsilon \phi] - F[x]}{\epsilon}$$
Here $\phi$ is a compactly supported smooth function and $\frac{\delta F[x]}{\delta x(t)}$ will be a distribution.

Comment: Hello, @md2perpe ! I am aware of the definition of variation of a functional, both the one you provide and Kiryl was talking about (it is frequently used in physics). However, the problem is that I can represent $\frac{du}{dx^{\mu}}[\frac{du}{dx^{\mu'}}]= \int \frac{du}{dx^{\mu'}} \delta(x-x') dx'$ my function as a functional of $\frac{du}{dx^{\mu'}}$, but struggle with its representation as a functional of $x^{\mu'}$. Therefore, I cannot apply any of definitions.

Comment: I don't get exactly what you want to do. What entity should be varied with respect to what variable?

Comment: @md2perpe I edited the question to include the origin of the problem